# User login not loading and not redirecting to dashboard

Tags: php

This is the message I got when user try to login on my website
home/actiqmlb/testrunbase.ml/core/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
    if($user->status == 1){
        $this->guard()->logout();
        session()->flash('message','Sorry Your Account is Block Now.!');
        session()->flash('type','danger');
        return redirect('/login');
    }

    $ip = NULL; $deep_detect = TRUE;

    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=".$ip);

    $country =  $xml->geoplugin_countryName ;
    $city = $xml->geoplugin_city;
    $area = $xml->geoplugin_areaCode;
    $code = $xml->geoplugin_countryCode;

    $user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";
    $os_array       =   array(
        '/windows nt 10/i'     =>  'Windows 10',
        '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
        '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
        '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
        '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
        '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
        '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
        '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
        '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
        '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
        '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
```

Arguments
"simplexml_load_file(http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=197.210.28.32): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"

Comment: Most likely geoplugin.net is blacklisting your server or ip due to too many calls from a script. 403 forbidden is access denied. Contact geoplugin.net about it. We cannot do anything for you.

Comment: How do I contact geoplugin.net

Comment: Please help give me some little guide